Unable to redirect back into Capacitor App when authenticating using firebase auth
I have recently extended my React webapp with Capacitor to produce a webview-based native app on android.
I am impressed with Capacitor so far, as the app was nearly completely functional out of the box, however I have run into a problem with authentication.
I am using firebase@8.3.1 (out of date), firebaseui@4.8.0 (also out of date) and capacitor@6.1.2
My firebase config contains the following relevant snippet:
queryParameterForSignInSuccessUrl: 'signInSuccessUrl',
signInFlow: 'popup',
signInSuccessUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://mindstack.app' :
    Capacitor.isNativePlatform() ? 'mindstack://' : '/',

with the intent here being

In production in browser, redirect to my website (this works fine)
In the app, redirect to a custom "mindstack://" scheme (This does not work)
Otherwise (local dev environment), redirect to "/" (this also works fine)

In my capacitor config, I have attempted to handle deeplinking for the "mindstack://" scheme using:
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'app.mindstack',
  appName: 'Mindstack',
  webDir: 'build',
  plugins: {
    Deeplinks: {
      schemes: ['mindstack'],
      handleUniversalLinks: true
    }
  }
};

and set up the handling of the intent in my AndroidManifest.xml as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="mindstack" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>

However, when I log in with firebase, I am unable to redirect back into my app. After clicking "login with google" in the app (made with firebaseui) I am redirected to a firebase auth URL in chrome, but then upon successful login I am simply redirected to "https://localhost/login" in chrome, and not to "mindstack://".
I am aware that the capacitor config I used for allowing deeplinks may be out of date an unsupported, and I am going to look into changing to use the way described here: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links
However I have become suspicious, as when I change the native app redirect URL from "mindstack://" to "https://www.bbc.com" I am still redirected to "https://localhost/login"  on login, which makes me wonder whether the redirects are working at all on the native app.
My firebase & firebaseui packages are also out of date, but this hasn't been a problem on web/mobile browsers, so I would be surprised if this was what was causing the problem with capacitor.
I am going to continue looking into this but would appreciate any insight if someone can see something I have missed
